# How to get all values exist in table - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want all the packages that contain exactly all the products inside.
No more, no less.
You can't check with the number because one of the products may be in the package but not one. Then it becomes one in terms of number.

```
  $result = \DB::table('Tb_Packages as TP')
            ->select('TP.*', \DB::raw('(select count(id) from Tb_Package_Products where package_id = TP.id) as count_products'))
            ->join('Tb_Package_Products as TPP', 'TP.id', '=', 'TPP.package_id')
            ->whereIn('TPP.product_id', $product_ids)
            ->havingRaw('count_products = ' . count($product_ids))
            ->get();
```

this wrong. because when in `Tb_Package_Products` table exsit products: 1 and 2;
and I use where in [1,4], my query return result!!!